# Merging data into new revisions of an ongoing spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup, importrange

I have a working spreadsheet I've whipped up for a small niche of the rhythm game community to use in tracking performance and song data across the current mix of songs for a given patch of the game.  When the developer releases a new patch, the song list on each tab is updated in a well-ordered fashion such that the new songs (i.e. rows of each tab) are interspersed within the new set of data.

**MY QUESTION**: How would I go about merging data from an older version of the tracklist into a sheet containing new data positions (i.e. rows) that weren't previously in the old sheet, since Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V won't work?[Here is what the old data set would be](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yfxEsxtGfPiyAcHdgNgZRDJKHRj6rg-bE0ODiWyloLw/edit?usp=sharing) which then needs to have itself merged into [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x89yRNhKyYmIE2m9Ng3VgabKNlgMWSUlRw-vmbfKSsY/edit?usp=sharing).

For those curious, here's a link to the full progress tracker: [PIU XX Tracker](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G5gWtTe859ozTnjnXTAnSUxpU8NviS6kG2XkIeghOBI/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome. Most likely this can be easily solved. Unfortunately, none of your sheets are accessible. Please change permissions to "anyone can edit" or just view. Here is [How to share a sheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w1hDceCQlEx_NEPy_BO7lnXo6552eELg/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: sheets are private

Comment: @marikamitsos, the sheets are fixed, sorry about that

Comment: fixed, @player0, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a lot of unknown how exactly is data served so let's assume the Update comes with new dates for new values and you want to import old dates for old values, then you will need to do simple arrayformula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, IMPORTRANGE(
 "1yfxEsxtGfPiyAcHdgNgZRDJKHRj6rg-bE0ODiWyloLw", 
 "Sheet1!A:B"), 2, 0), B2:B))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: what is the argument "1yfxEsx..." referencing? Is it the hyperlink to the previous Google Sheet?

Comment: that's the sheet ID. code in URL of the sheet between **d/** and **/edit**